# Rotating a Geoplot polyplot

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I currently have the function:

```
def cross_country(contiguous_usa, full_geo_data):

    full_geo_data['Coordinates'] = full_geo_data[['longitude', 'latitude']].values.tolist()
    full_geo_data['Coordinates'] = full_geo_data['Coordinates'].apply(Point)
    full_geo_data = gpd.GeoDataFrame(full_geo_data, geometry='Coordinates')

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,15))

    ax1 = plt.subplot(212, projection=gcrs.AlbersEqualArea(central_latitude=-98, central_longitude=39.5))

    gplt.kdeplot(full_geo_data[full_geo_data['speedkmh'] == 0],
             projection=gcrs.AlbersEqualArea(), cmap="cool", clip=contiguous_usa.geometry, ax=ax1)

    gplt.polyplot(contiguous_usa, projection=gcrs.AlbersEqualArea(), ax=ax1)
    plt.title("Test")
cross_country(contiguous_usa, full_geo_data)
```

It works fine however, when I run it the map comes out as such:

[image: The orientation is not nominal]

I know its a trivial thing to ask, but I've looked into the documentation and I can't find anything that relates to changing basic orientation, for literally just rotating the plot.

Comment: Try using `central_latitude=39.5, central_longitude=-98` in your code.

Comment: I did that, the plot rotated by 45 degrees. Since its a projection its really funky in regards to plot orientation, and Matplotlib's `orientation` wrapper isn't recognized.

Comment: Additionally, drop `projection=gcrs.AlbersEqualArea()` in the lines that starts with `gplt.kdeplot` and `gplt.polyplot`. The option `ax=ax1` intrinsically define proper projection already.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest answer likely involves the projection or crs you are using. However, if you can't get that to work, you can use shapely to modify individual rows of the geodataframe.

```
def rotator(row):
    row['geometry'] = shapely.affinity.rotate(row['geometry'], -90)
    return row

full_geo_data = full_geo_data.apply(rotator, axis = 1)
```